# terraform error message line numbers

Tags: terraform

Is there any way to get the line number causing terraform errors?  For example:

```
$ terraform plan
module root: module foo: bar is not a valid parameter
$
```

Ideally the error message would give me file paths and line numbers corresponding to the error, e.g.

```
$ terraform plan
  File "maint.tf", line 120:
    bar = "123"
  InvalidParameterError: "bar" is not a valid parameter of module foo
$
```

I understand not being a procedural language may make this more difficult but not containing a single file path nor line number seems excessive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, there isn't currently a way to make terraform output the error file or line location

This is a known usability issue with terraform, and the maintainers are updating error messages on a case-by-case basis. (see https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/1758).

Per mitchellh, "error messages are improving," but for now it seems that humans will have to find the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Due to how terraform state is managed, there aren't always line numbers for an error to map to. Syntactical errors should result in a line number, but there are some scenarios where you'll error because of the terraform state (on disk, on in s3, etc).

For example, the following is a valid main.tf file:

```
terraform { }
```

So running `terraform apply` on the above should work right? Yes, unless the terraform state is tracking a resource which still requires a provider.

Let's say your terraform state matches the following `main.tf` file.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    foo_provider { ..source and version }
  }
}

provider "foo_provider" {
  domain = "this is be a required field"
}

resource "foo_resource" {
  name = "bar"
}
```

If you remove everything `foo*`, the terraform state is still tracking the the `foo_resoruce`, so you can't just run `terraform apply` against an empty `main.tf` file.

Let's say you do anyway. Run `terraform apply` against the empty `main.tf`

```
terraform { }
```

You will probably get an error like the following `The argument "domain" is required, but was not set.` ..and **there will be no line number**! The error can be super generic and have no mention of the resource or provider causing it. It comes from your terraform tracked state, not syntax. You have to remove the resource from terraform's tracked state before removing the provider (and it's required arguments).

Comment: That makes sense -- thanks for explaining! Honestly though it makes me question whether the high level design of Terraform is broken and if there is a better way.